# Finding correct php regex for this complex element

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to get a regex which is able to find the following part in a string.

```
[TABLE|head,border|{
#TEXT|TEXT|TEXT#
TEXT|TEXT|TEXT
TEXT|TEXT|TEXT
TEXT|TEXT|TEXT
}]
```

Its from a simple self made WYSIWYG Editor, which gives the possibility to add tables. But the "syntax" for a table should be as simple as the one above.

No as there can be many of these table definitions, I need to find all with php's preg_match_all to replace them with the well known `<table>` tag in html.

The regex iam trying to use for is the following:

```
/\[TABLE\|(.*)\|\{(.*)\}\]/si
```

The `\x0A` stays for a newline as my app is running on Linux this is enough (works fine with simpler regex).

I use the online regex tester on [functions-online.com](http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match_all.html).

The matches it gets are not really usefull. And if i have more than one TABLE definition like the one above, then the matches are completely useless. Because of the (.*) it covers all from starting from "head,border" going to the very last "|" character in the second TABLE definition.

I would like to get a list of matches giving me the complete table command one by one.

Comment: I can't play with it right now but if you're on Windows you should try http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/ for working with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because by default the .* will be a greedy match, assuming your code works correctly for an input containing only a single value. Placing a question mark after the two .*'s should prevent greedyness being an issue.

```
/\[TABLE\|(.*?)\|\{(.*?)\}\]/si
```

Comment: Oh my god it was only the missing question mark?
Its working.

Lost hours because of 2 characters. 8-|

Thanks a lot Cags.